# django field edit on creation (value on creation, not update)

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a field, that it's value can be set on creation only (via admin) and can't change later.
The use is for accounting accounts, that sets currency, and cannot be changed later.
editable=True, but only on update, not creation.
Is such a thing possible?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your model admin you can override the `get_form` method to allow only changes to the field on creation:

```
def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
    # if updating...
    if obj:
        self.readonly_fields = ['currency']
    # if creating...
    else:
        self.readonly_fields = []
    return super().get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
```